# Using structure on existing site

Tags: structure

I have a site that was developed several years ago by someone else, using an addon cpNavBreadcrumb, about which I can find no information at all on the net!!! I just upgraded the site from ee 1.6.7 to ee 2.5.5 and all of the pages which reference cpNavBreadcrumb (ie all except the homepage) did not load until I commented out the relevant code.

I have installed Structure which I was hoping to use to replace cpNavBreadcrumb, but it appears that this is not a straightforward as I had hoped.

How do you add Structure to an existing site?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to follow the setup and intro articles from our Getting Started section here: http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation

You would setup the channels you want Structure to use and resave them, dragging them into place in the hierarchy and then adding our dynamic tags to your templates for the navigation.